# Doubt about a phrase on SE profile bio

Tags: word-usage

If you look at the bio of a not edited profile on SE, you will find this:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

Why did they use "them" instead of "himself"?

Comment: Is your question why a reflexive wasn't used, or why a gender-neutral pronoun was used, or both?

Comment: I never heard about "gender-neutral pronouns"

Comment: Are you asking why a reflexive "themself"/"themselves" form wasn't used, or are you asking why "them" was used rather than "him", or both?

Comment: I tought that "them" was wrong at all in grammar, i just learned that this is an acceptable form by @Jasper's answer

Comment: Ah, I see. :)  Since the original has a non-reflexive ("them") and you suggested a reflexive ("himself" rather than "him"), I thought you might be asking why the reflexive wasn't used.  FWIW I think the reflexive is optional here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Them](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/them)* here is used as a gender-neutral pronoun in place of *him* or *her*. Similarly, *[they](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/they)* is used as a gender-neutral pronoun in place of *he* or *she*.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that, i tought it was an error

Comment: @MarcoSalerno prescriptively, it's an error. But it's completely idiomatic.